# Convergence/Divergence of an Infinite Series with Natural Logarithms

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, logarithms, divergent-series

I've spent a good week and half manipulating and trying different tests to find the convergence or divergence of this series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$$

I've tried all the Convergence Tests I know, and have tried to exhaust the Ratio Test for many different manipulations of the above, including
$\ln n^{-\ln n}$, $\ln n^{\ln(1/n)}$, and, using the relationship $a^x = e^{x\ln a}$, $e^{\ln(1/n)*\ln(\ln(n))}\implies(1/n)^{\ln(\ln n)}$.

Basically, I'm just burnt out trying to solve this, and came for any help someone on here can offer me.

Cheers.

EDIT: the only hint we're given is to note that $n > e^2$.

Comment: Perhaps that you meant $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{(\log n)^{\log n}}$.

Comment: No, the question uses natural logarithms.

Comment: @anyone The base of the logarithm is (probably) immaterial. Compare the comment with the sum in the question: they are entirely different.

Comment: Hint: try Cauchy-condensation test. It is very good for series with logarithms.

Comment: I believe @JoséCarlosSantos is pointing out that at $n=0$ and $n=1$, the summand is undefined. (Also $\log$ is a common notation for natural log)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT:

$$(\ln n)^{\ln n} = n ^{\ln \ln n} > n^2$$
for all $n > n_0$. So
$$\frac{1}{n ^{\ln \ln n}} < \frac{1}{n^2}$$

Then use comparison test